# Kafka increase throughput with multiple partition and multiple consumer threads

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am using kafka stream for some application.

Stream flow is like below

```
kafkaProducer---->StreamerConsumer1->finalCosumer
```

I have producer which write the data very fast and my StreamConsumer  will map each stream with some process and forward the stream to other topic.

in my StreamCosumer map, I added my own mapper function which Actually tries to persist its relevant data like below

```
public void checkRecord(T1 key, T2 value) {
 switch(T1.toString()){
 case "key1":
  //Get relavant fileds from value and perisit in db 
   break;
   case "key2":
     //Get relavant fileds from value and perisit in db 
   break;
 }
}


KStream<String, KafkaStatusRecordWrapper> pDStream[] = myStream.map(this::checkRecord).branch((key, value)-> value.isSuccess(),(key, value)-> !value.isSuccess());

pDStream[0].mapValues(value -> transformer(value)).to("other_topic",Produced.with(stringSerde, stringSerde));
```

Now my checkRecord record consumer function is single threaded and almost it is taking 300ms(due to some business logic and db persist which I can not avoid) to return.

I can not increase the number of partition as there was some limitation from our infra, and also due to below constraints

```
More Partitions Requires More Open File Handles
More Partitions May Increase Unavailability
More Partitions May Increase End-to-end Latency
```

so I am planning to write multi-threaded stream consumer.

But I am concerned about below points.

1. I need to process record only once
2. Handing off to another thread will cause problems with offset management.

So how to increase throughput ?

I have enough resource on my consumer, only 40% of its resource are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the stream configuration `num.stream.threads` to configure the number of threads. Maximum value could be the maximum number of partitions. It helps to increase the parallelism of the application instance.

Let's say if your topic has 4 partitions, you can set following:

```
properties.set("num.stream.threads",4);
```

Comment: Due to some reason I can not increase the partition more than10. I need to have some logic based on the writing multiple thread for each stream task ..but I dont know How to manage offest commit in multiple  threads for each stream task